# How to access Google Cloud Bucket from development Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to access my Google Cloud Bucket from development environment but when I write import statement I get error

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

Command I use to run server with bucket flag

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml --default_gcs_bucket_name ABC-test-bucket
```

Error I get

```
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\setuptools-0.6c11\pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
DistributionNotFound: google-cloud-storage
```

I think I completed all the steps like creating bucket, downloading client library using pip i.e.

```
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <your_app_directory/lib>
```

I am new to GAE projects(Using Webapp2 Python framework for server) so I will really appreciate any pointers and help

Answer (score 0):

The library you're using is not the correct one. You need the one below, as per [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python):

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```